# How to modify the ulimit of a process created by docker service

Tags: docker, centos, file-descriptor, ulimit

I have set ulimit soft and hard **8196** on both

> docker-compose.yml

file as well as host machine at

> /etc/security/limits.conf

but when I see the process Max Open Files at

> cat /proc/pid/limit

soft limit it's still 1024.

Comment: Not sure how this is an on-topic question for SO.